# Access $model in the fields function (laravel nova)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

```
public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
{
    if (IBAN::find($model->id_user)->iban ?? false) {
     return [
          // Exemple
     ];
    }
    else {
     return [
          Text::make("IBAN:", 'iban')->required()->rules('required')->placeholder("PT000000"),
     ];
    }
}
```

I need to access $models in the fields function to get the id of the selected user.

I tried to use:

```
$request->user()->id
```

Instead of using:

```
$model->user_id
```

When I use `$request->user()->id` it returns my account id instead of returning the id of the selected user.

But if I do `$model->user_id` in the handle function it returns the id of the selected user correctly.

How can I access the $model in the fields function?

Comment: What it´s $model.

i understand that $model it´s a declared variable with this name. but if you want IBAN´s object by id... you should send IBAN´s id. Idon´t understand very well your question. But i believe that you need send IBAN´s id not user_id or user()->id because laravel search by column id not other column. if you want search your IBAN by user, you should to do a query with where

Comment: Can you not inject the `$model` object into the `fields(NovaRequest $request)` method? `fields(NovaRequest $request, $model)`

Comment: No, they are predefined functions of the laravel nova

Comment: How about you use `$this->resource->user()->iban`? $this->resource is available during fields() function and will return the model.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Nova resource injects the Model to each resource object
So in the table, every row is an object from the resource class so directly you can use recourse object like below

```
public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
{
    if (IBAN::find($**this**->id_user)->iban ?? false) {
     return [
          // Exemple
     ];
    }
    else {
     return [
          Text::make("IBAN:", 'iban')->required()->rules('required')->placeholder("PT000000"),
     ];
    }
}
```